# Вернуть из jquery-запроса html код с php-бека

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
        $.get('***/ajax.php',
            {method : "getReport", month: $('#month').val(), year:$('#year').val()},function (data){
            console.log('123');
            $('#report').replaceWith(data);
        });
    }
```

Есть такой код. Он отправляет запрос на бекенд, который должен вернуть просто html-код, что он и делает:
[image: Инструменты разработчика]

Но данный html не заменяется(элемент с айди - report - существует).
Ставил точку останова на console.log(123) - в точку не заходит.

Как решить эту проблему?
На беке просто формируется этот html:
[image: Код бека]

Comment: Нужно читать [документацию](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) внимательнее.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, мог бы цену себе не набивать, а сказать, в чём ошибка.

Comment: мне вот что-то тоже не понятно, что там надо внимательнее читать

Comment: Может вы ещё покажете куда вы вставляете данный html код?

Comment: Ну раз тут считают что я набиваю себе цену, значит мой ресурс помощи другим исчерпан. Аривидерчи, SO! :)

Comment: заголовки ответа в студию

Comment: сделайте обработку ошибки ajax-запроса и выведите ее в консоль.